# What is the Kohn anomaly?

Tags: density-functional-theory, phonons

I have been unable to figure out what the Kohn anomaly is. What exactly is it, and why is it important?

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/366/5. Also I agree with Cody, if you can tell us what you have looked at so far, that would make your answer more upvoted.

Comment: The upvote button says "This question shows research effort...", probably need to do that.